# Class 'Database\\SQLite3' not found

Tags: ubuntu, php, sqlite

I've encoutered some problems with SQLite3 for **PHP 7** on **Ubuntu 16.04** LTS. After installing the module via `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`.

Now, im trying to run this code:

```
<?php
namespace Database;

class Database extends SQLite3
{ 
...
}
```

Its always failing. The Error.log reports the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Database\\SQLite3' not found in /var/www/public/test/app/Database.php on line 4
```

If using phpinfo() and looking for SQLite3, I get the following:

[Screenshot of phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhFMZ.png)

Go you have any idea whats wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are in namespace `Database` so the class `SQLite3` is searched inside this namespace but it's not there. Use a FQCN or a use-statement to find the correct class.

```
<?php
namespace Database;

class Database extends \SQLite3
{ 
...
}
```

or

```
<?php
namespace Database;

use SQLite3;

class Database extends SQLite3
{ 
...
}
```